# Sort images by date into subdirecories

Tags: files, mv

I have a directory with sub-directories that contains images.I want to make a new directory and move all the images in there and then sort them to sub-directories with the order `year/month/day` of modification.

I thought of using `find` and `mv` to move all the images to the new directory, find the date of first image in directory, make a sub-directory named after the year of this image and then find and move all the  images with the same year in that sub-directory.I will do this for every image in the main directory and then I will repeat the procedure in every sub-directory for month and then day.

My problem is that I believe that there must be a sorter way for me to do this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh`:

```
zmodload zsh/files # bring in builtin versions of mkdir and mv to speed things up
zmodload zsh/stat

for file (**/*.jpg(N.)) {
   zstat -F %Y/%m/%d -A date +mtime -- $file &&
     mkdir -p $date &&
     mv -- $file $date
}
```

If you don't have `zsh` and can't install it, with GNU tools, you could minimize the number of commands run with:

```
(export LC_ALL=C
  find . -name '*.jpg' -type f -printf '%TY/%Tm/%Td\0%p\0' |
    gawk -v 'RS=\0' -v q="'" '
      function shquote(s) {
        gsub(q, q "\\" q q, s)
        return q s q
      }
      {
        date = $0; getline file
        dir[date] = dir[date] " " shquote(file)
      }
      END {
        printf "mkdir -p ."
        for (d in dir) printf " %s", d
        print " || exit"
        for (d in dir) print "mv" dir[d], d
      }' | sh
)
```

(you may want to remove the `| sh` at first to check that it does what you want).

Note that neither of those will guard against conflicts. For instance, if you have a `a/foo.jpg` and `b/foo.jpg` both last modified on 2017-11-01, they will both be moved to `2017/11/01/foo.jpg`, one of them overwriting the other. You may want to add the `-i` flag to `mv` to guard against it.